# Android Camera Preview doesn't start after calling android camera parameters on Unity3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-camera

I´m trying to start camera after getting float parameters from `android.hardware.camera.getparameters` and put it on a `GUI.Button`, but when I run the App on Android I get a black screen. Over the black screen the `GUI.button` or the camera preview. But not the `GUI.button` depending if I call the float first or the camera.
 Has someone any idea about where the problem is? I'm a beginner and I don't know where can I look for the problem.

Here is my code:

```java
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Cam : MonoBehaviour {

    //variables privadas
    public static WebCamDevice[] devices = WebCamTexture.devices;
    private static float VerticalViewAngle;
    private float mi;

    //variables publicas



    void Awake () {
        //mi = hva ();
        Playcam ();
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        GUI.Button(new Rect(0,0,Screen.width,20),mi.ToString("F4"));
    }

    void OnGUI () {

    }
    // funciones

    public static Texture Startcamera(){

        //WebCamDevice cam = WebCamDevice();
        WebCamDevice cam = devices [0];
        WebCamTexture webCameraTexture  =    new WebCamTexture(cam.name);
        webCameraTexture.deviceName  = cam.name;
        webCameraTexture.Play();
        return webCameraTexture;

    }
    //gnereacion de variables
    public static float hva ()
    {

        AndroidJavaClass cameraClass = new AndroidJavaClass ("android.hardware.Camera");
        int camID = 0;
        AndroidJavaObject camera = cameraClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject> ("open", camID);

        AndroidJavaObject cameraParameters = camera.Call<AndroidJavaObject> ("getParameters");
        VerticalViewAngle = cameraParameters.Call<float>("getFocalLength");
        //Debug.Log ("miguel                     "+ VerticalViewAngle);
        //Debug.Log ("fernando                     "+ VerticalViewAngle);
        return VerticalViewAngle;

    }

     public void  Playcam () {
        GUITexture BackgroundTexture = gameObject.AddComponent<GUITexture>();
           BackgroundTexture.pixelInset = new Rect(0,0,Screen.width,Screen.height);
        BackgroundTexture.texture = Startcamera ();
    }
}
```

that is my androidmanifest.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
 android:installLocation="preferExternal"
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
        <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:debuggable="false">
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.VideoPlayer"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
        </activity>
        <!--
            To support devices using the TI S3D library for stereo mode we must 
            add the following library.
            Devices that require this are: ODG X6 
        -->
        <uses-library android:name="com.ti.s3d" android:required="false" />
        <!--
            To support the ODG R7 in stereo mode we must add the following library.
        -->
        <uses-library android:name="com.osterhoutgroup.api.ext" android:required="false" />
    </application>
</manifest>

<!-- android:installLocation="preferExternal" -->
```

Comment: Share additional details, such as AndroidManifest, the overall function expect, and any logcat if you see failures.

Comment: I edit the post including my android manifest, but i can't find the error in logcat, the code is attached over a camera in unity, maybe the problem could be in around the permission that i give with WebCamDevice cam = WebCamDevice(); becouse it seems that when i try to call the float parameter there is a conflict between camera.call and float call trouhgt AndroidJavaClas or AndroidJavaObject

Comment: I have finded in logcat the next error:

Comment: E/Unity <28510> Unable to initialize camera:fail to connect to camera service

Comment: w/CameraService<1464>:CameraService::connect X<pid 28510> rejected <existing client>.

Comment: Edit your question, place the logcat, as it is more likely to find the cause of the failure... Also, google the error in itself, as you could find the problem